# Js flip/unflip with same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, flip

**Hi I want to make a button that first flip the image and then on next click it will unflip it**...
I tried a lot of methods but didn't work for me..

```
    $('.button').on("click", function (){ 
$('#image').css("transform","scaleX(-1)");
})
```

Comment: People are downvoting your question, because it's one that can be answered quickly, by using Stack Overflow's search:   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+flip+image

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a flag variable to keep an record of changes. like

```js
var flipFlag = 0 // initialy unfliped condition
$('.button').on("click", function (){ 
if(flipFlag == 0)
{
  $('#image').css("transform","scaleX(-1)"); // flip form
  flipFlag=1;                                // 1 to say fliped
}
else
{
  $('#image').css("transform","scaleX(0)"); // original form
  flipFlag=0;                               // 0 to say unfliped
}

});
```

hope this will help you out, Thank you